# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I am creating a `Dynamic CRM 2011 Report` in `SSRS`.
I use several joins, And use GUID in joins.
For ex :

```
Quote.OpportunityId=Opprtunity.OpportunityId
```

The problem comes from `parameters`.
I have a `parameter` which its label is a name and the value is GUID of a record.
I retrieve them from a Dataset.
The query of the this Dataset(named siteDataset) is this :

```
select site.SiteId, site.Name from Site;
```

the `siteId` goes to the value of the parameter and `site.name` goes to the label of the parameter, the Parameter is named `siteId` itself.

But when I try to do this in another DataSet :

```
siteGUIDInAnotherEntity='@siteId'
```

Give me the subject Error.
I even tried this :

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), site.SiteId)
```

in siteId DataSet; But no success.

Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a typo in your question, but just to be safe I'll post this as a possible answer - you shouldn't have those single quotes around @siteId, it should be like this:

```
siteGUIDInAnotherEntity=@siteId
```

The text string '@siteId' can't be converted into a `uniqueidentifier` for that join, and will result in the error you mentioned:

```
SELECT CAST('@siteId' AS uniqueidentifier);
```

> Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.